# Table column width stretched

Tags: html, css, html-table

Can someone explain to me why my table isn't laying out the way I would expect?
The column displaying the phone numbers should be as wide as possible, but the cell with the email address is making the column with the number labels wider?

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaArmadillo/UX3pH/

```
<table width='100%' border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='5'>PIC</td>
    <td colspan='2'>First Lastname</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Users Position</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>emailaddress.emailaddress@emailaddress.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>business:</span></td>
    <td width='100%'><span>123-4567</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>mobile:</span></td>
    <td width='100%'><span>765-4321</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*P.S. Please no "You should use DIVs!", I know, this is a small part of a much larger layout and I couldn't get everything to work with DIVs and I'm running out of time, v2.0 will be refactored to use DIVs (If I can get time to make them work)*

Comment: For me the layout is working the way you want it to (with my interpretation of your requirement). Can you post a screenshot of the expected layout?

Comment: Same here... you set your table width to 100%, thus your total table is going to be 100% width of the screen. This means that every row is going to be 100% wide. It does not matter if there is one or two columns.

Comment: i think he just wants the number cells maximised in width

Comment: guys, i think he wants it to look like this : http://jsfiddle.net/UX3pH/8/

Comment: Oliver is correct, I want the cells the numbers are in the be as wide as possible. In the examples if you make the email very small it displays what I would consider properly, but if you make it longer it's making the label cells wider, which is weird to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you `td{width:5%}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yYeUL/)

Comment: i think he wanted the number labels shrunk to as little width as possible.